# How to make mouse over event of clip underneath still work?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Hi was hoping someone could help me with this MOUSE_OVER event issue

I'm triggering the appearance of a tooltip via MOUSE_OVER on a button and I'm finding it keeps getting triggered if I keep the mouse pointer over the tooltip. Both the tooltip and button are MovieClips

How can I prevent this?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
for(var i:Number=0; i < MapContainer.numChildren; i++) {
    var Country:MovieClip = MapContainer.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
    if(Country){ // make sure its a movieclip
        trace('Found movieclip');
        addInfoBubble(Country);
        Country.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, countryMouseOver);
        Country.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, countryMouseOut);
    } 

}

function showInfoBubble(Country:MovieClip){

    var bubble = getChildByName(Country.name+"Info");
    trace("bubble name " + bubble);
    bubble.visible = true;
    TweenLite.to(bubble, .5, {alpha:1});

}

function hideInfoBubble(Country:MovieClip){
    var bubble = getChildByName(Country.name+"Info");
    bubble.alpha = 0;
    bubble.visible = false;
    //removeChild(CountryInfo);
    //CountryInfo = null;
}

function countryMouseOver(e:Event):void{
    trace('countryMouseOver '+e.target);
    var countryMc = e.target;
    var localPos:Point = new Point(countryMc.x,countryMc.y);
    var globalPos:Point = countryMc.localToGlobal(localPos);
    trace('local pos: '+localPos+ ' global pos:'+globalPos);

    TweenLite.to(countryMc, 1, {tint:mouseOverColor});

    showInfoBubble(countryMc);
}

function countryMouseOut(e:Event):void{
    trace('countryMouseOut '+e.target);
    var countryMc = e.target;
    var localPos:Point = new Point(countryMc.x,countryMc.y);
    var globalPos:Point = countryMc.localToGlobal(localPos);
    trace('local pos: '+localPos+ ' global pos:'+globalPos);

    TweenLite.to(countryMc, 1, {tint:mouseOutColor});
    hideInfoBubble(countryMc);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you create the `bubble` MovieClip (looks like it's in addInfoBubble), set `bubble.mouseEnabled = false;`.

Also, as you can see from the StackOverflow syntax highlighting, by convention variables usually start with a lower-case name, classes with an upper-case name (Country parameters should be country).

Comment: Hi @Sean Fujiwara, so I added mouseEnabled per below and the tooltip still blinks and the button underneath never finishes its transition -  something else Im missing? Also, as for naming conventions, when you create a new object would you capitalize that?


`function addInfoBubble(country:MovieClip) {
 var localPos:Point = new Point(country.x,country.y);
 var globalPos:Point =   country.parent.localToGlobal(localPos);
 var countryInfo:MovieClip = new InfoBubble();
 countryInfo.name = country.name+"Info";
 countryInfo.mouseEnabled = false;`

Comment: Re the mouse issue turns out I also need to tell Flash to ignore mouse events on children of the countryInfo/bubble

`countryInfo.mouseEnabled = false;

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  All the casing in your comment looks good.